# docker rabbitmq hostname issue

Tags: rabbitmq, docker

I am build an image using Dockerfile, and I would like to add users to RabbitMQ right after installation. The problem is that during build hostname of the docker container is different from when I run the resultant image. RabbitMQ loses that user; because of changed hostname it uses another DB.

I connot change `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files from inside a container, and looks that RabbitMQ is not picking my changes to `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` and `HOSTNAME` variables.

The only thing that I found working is running this before starting RabbitMQ broker:

```
echo "NODENAME=rabbit@localhost" >> /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf.d/ewos.conf
```

But then I will have to run docker image with changed hostname all the time.

```
docker run -h="localhost" image
```

Any ideas on what can be done? Maybe the solution is to add users to RabbitMQ not on build but on image run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest to add users when the container runs for the first time.

Instead of starting RabbitMQ directly, you can run a wrapper script that will take care of all the setup, and then start RabbitMQ. If the last step of the wrapper script is a process start, remember that you can use `exec` so that the new process replaces the script itself.

Comment: Also there was a problem: when I add a user and right after that stop RabbitMQ, added user is not persisted. Adding a bit of ``sleep 3`` before RabbitMQ stop command resolved the issue.

Comment: This is not solution, because images should be built from Dockerfile, not that you have to run container to set things up every time you do deployment from docker image.

Comment: @Rubycut you are right. Have you tested, your answer below? I haven't seen command execution separated by semicolons till this time. Did you encounter the problem with persisting configs like I did above?

Comment: Yes, I've use it last week on latest version of Rabbitmq and latest docker version.

Semicolons work fine, you can even use \ to go to next line if line is too long. You can also use && instead of semicolons.

Yes, I had persisting problem until I changed HOSTNAME, now everything is persisted properly.

Answer (score 6):

Just here is example how to configure from Dockerfile properly:

```
ENV HOSTNAME localhost

RUN /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start ; rabbitmqctl add_vhost /test; /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop
```

This is remember your config.

Comment: Seems to work. Unsure of the implications of calling the node localhost though.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:jessie

MAINTAINER Francesco Casula <fra.casula@gmail.com>

VOLUME ["/var/www"]
WORKDIR /var/www

ENV HOSTNAME my-docker
ENV RABBITMQ_NODENAME rabbit@my-docker

COPY scripts /root/scripts

RUN /bin/bash /root/scripts/os-setup.bash && \
    /bin/bash /root/scripts/install-rabbitmq.bash

CMD /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start && \
    /bin/bash
```

**os-setup.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" > /etc/hosts
echo "127.0.1.1 my-docker" >> /etc/hosts

echo "my-docker" > /etc/hostname
```

**install-rabbitmq.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "NODENAME=rabbit@my-docker" > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf

echo 'deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list
wget -O- https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | apt-key add -
apt-get update

cd ~
wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-server_3.6.5-1_all.deb
dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.6.5-1_all.deb
apt-get install -f -y

/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start

sleep 3

rabbitmq-plugins enable amqp_client mochiweb rabbitmq_management rabbitmq_management_agent \
                        rabbitmq_management_visualiser rabbitmq_web_dispatch webmachine

rabbitmqctl delete_user guest
rabbitmqctl add_user bunny password
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags bunny administrator
rabbitmqctl delete_vhost /
rabbitmqctl add_vhost symfony_prod
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p symfony_prod bunny ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmqctl add_vhost symfony_dev
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p symfony_dev bunny ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmqctl add_vhost symfony_test
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p symfony_test bunny ".*" ".*" ".*"

/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart

IS_RABBIT_INSTALLED=`rabbitmqctl status | grep RabbitMQ | grep "3\.6\.5" | wc -l`

if [ "$IS_RABBIT_INSTALLED" = "0" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

IS_RABBIT_CONFIGURED=`rabbitmqctl list_users | grep bunny | grep "administrator" | wc -l`

if [ "$IS_RABBIT_CONFIGURED" = "0" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Don't forget to run the container by specifying the right host with the `-h` flag:

```
docker run -h my-docker -it --name=my-docker -v $(pwd)/htdocs:/var/www my-docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me was to change default value in **rabbitmq-env.conf**  of **MNESIA_BASE** property to **MNESIA_BASE=/data** and I added this command **RUN mkdir /data** in Dockerfile before starting server and add users.